different buffers yet same address
So I want to quote from the C++ documentation regarding cin.ignore where it states:

it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object

Now I tried playing around and would like to confirm something in the following example.
#include<iostream>      
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char strArr1[6];
    char strArr2[6];
    cin.get(strArr1, 6, 'c'); // did this in order to get c in the buffer
    cout << "strArr1 is" << endl; // ENTER Issac
    cout << strArr1 << endl; // Issa
    cin.ignore(3, 'p') >> strArr2; // ENTER Howard
    cout << "strArr2 is" << endl; 
    cout << strArr2 << endl; // oward
    return 0;
}


In this case, strArr1 is "Issa" and it leaves the "c" in the buffer. Now in cin.ignore, we include the "c" that was in the buffer, the null ending character of strArr1, and the "H" as the first letter of "Howard". This is my conclusion but I would like to confirm the correctness of my conclusion with C++ experts. I assume both cins uses the same stream buffer because when I cout the address of both cins, it was the same.
Any confirmation of this conclusion would be very appreciated.

It's std::cin, so you don't instantiate several streams. It's just the stdin, as it's called. The 2 other terminal streams are stdout and stderr. If you'd instantiate a stream or file buffer, even as an input stream, that'd have a different address to it, since it's a different instance of a different object. Same as if you'd have 2 file stream instances or 2 string stream instances even of the same type.

And what exactly do you mean by buffer? std::cin is not a buffer per-se. It does have an internally handled allocation as a buffer, but I think you're confusing it with the instance of std::cin itself. By the way, drop the bad practice habit of using namespace std;. Even for tests. Yes I know tons of websites use it, hundreds of tutorials use it and a lot of videos show it, but drop it, it's bad practice. Same for other namespaces in general (except maybe in situational cases which should not be common).

"... in cin.ignore, we include [...], the null ending character of strArr1 ..." - No. cin.ignore doesn't have anything to do what's in strArr1.

Also, regarding "and it leaves the "c" in the buffer" there might be a misunderstanding here. There isn't some sort of area where anything you type is stored then if it's used, it's used, if it's ignored, it takes up "space" (or at least, that's what you make it sound like) just as if you'd have a box filled with balls and if you use the ball, you take it out, if not, you leave it in the box. It's rather you take out the balls from the box, but you throw away the ones you don't need. So if you have 10 balls and you took out 7, ignored 1, you'd have 6 in your hand and 3 (not 4) in the box.

@TedLyngmo well then if the null ending character is not included nor the "c" in the buffer, then why do we get "oward" and not "ard"?

@TheNomad makes sense as cin is a global object when we do #include and I did not know it was a bad practice but what could be the harm in using it for demonstrations?

Whatever gets into strArr2 comes from cin. It has no connection to strArr1 (which has a null terminator). cin.ignore(3) skipps c, whitespace and H.

@TheNomad yeah cin.ignore will ignore 3 characters or the 'p' in which case, there is no ''p'. But what 3 characters will it ignore? The last 2 characters in strArr1 and the first character in strArr2 make it "oward" or the first 3 characters in strArr2 making it "ard" (which is not what happens)? A comment mentioned that the former is not what happens and now I am a bit confused.

@TedLyngmo where did the whitespace come from?

The whitespace is what you entered after Issac. Was it newline or space? The point is that cin has no idea about strArr1 when you do ignore(3).

@TedLyngmo it was a newline.

Ok, that's the whitespace character that ignore will ignore then.

@TedLyngmo I would assume that this still counts as a character.

Yes, and it's not a character in strArr1

@IssacHoward "what could be the harm in using it for demonstrations?". If you discipline yourself in using best practices or strict standards and you make exceptions for "the easy way" which is not necessarily the best way, in time those exceptions might become your new rule. Also, with all due respect to experts, generally speaking, it's hard to take an expert seriously when they're breaking standard or best practices even "just this once" without proper reason other than "it's easier". Also, if a PoC works, you might copy it in production code and say "I'll make it proper code later".

Side note: Howard is six characters and will not fit in char strArr2[6]; because of the need for a terminating null character.

@user4581301 Great minds think alike ;) I covered that in the answer. But I think he did it on purpose to test ignore() since he didn't do char[5] for "Isaac" in strArray1.

OK, following your new line of questions I think I understand where your confusion is coming from.
The behavior of the code is hard to understand if you don't understand the workflow. When you did cin.get(strArr1, 6, 'c') you told it to stop at 'c'. But that wasn't the last character, as you did press Enter later on. The third character was 'h', just as Ted said.
The behavior of the code is hard to understand if you don't understand the workflow. cin.ignore(3, 'p') >> strArr2; returns something, but what? void? int? NULL? nullptr? std::cout? std::cin? All of them? None? If so, why?
Let's look at the documentation on C++ Reference (which I prefer over cplusplus.com) since it's a community maintained wiki and has less wooden language, and I personally find it better structured as a website (once you understand the reasoning behind it).
Taken from [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::ignore][2]:

Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including delim.
ignore behaves as an UnformattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, it extracts characters from the stream and discards them until any of the following conditions occurs:

count characters were extracted. This test is disabled in the special case when count equals std::numeric_limitsstd::streamsize::max().

end of file conditions occurs in the input sequence, in which case the function calls setstate(eofbit).

the next available character c in the input sequence is delim, as determined by Traits::eq_int_type(Traits::to_int_type(c), delim). The delimiter character is extracted and discarded. This test is disabled if delim is Traits::eof().


Parameters
count     -   number of characters to extract
delim     -   delimiting character to stop the extraction at. It is also extracted
Return value
*this

So as you can see, since it's a member function, when it's called it returns the current object on which it is called. So std::cin.ignore() will return cin itself.
This: cin.ignore(3, 'p') >> strArray2 is basically doing
cin.ignore(3, 'p');
cin >> strArray2;

... just as seen here.
This should clarify the relationship between the variables, the stdin and stdout, but now, you might try to follow how this and apply it to what we discussed in the comments and possibly be confused. By now it's clear that strArray1 and strArray2 are out of the equation. But what about std::cin, "Isaac", "Howard", the 'c' and 'p'?
Remember I did say that there is allocated memory for data to be stored or used by streams and you can think that as a sort of a buffer (just be very careful how you use this term when speaking of C and C++).
The way your post sounded is attributing or relating the behavior of ignore() to get(). The reason the program reacts like this is because you can think of the input streams as a feeder. In order for it to be consumed they need continuous data (which the prompt offers), but it also needs to be "eaten". get() only "ate" 4 characters, because you told it to stop at c. ignore() disregarded it and the next 2 characters. In comparison, look at this code:
#include<iostream>      

int main() {
    char strArr1[6];
    char strArr2[6];
    std::cin.get(strArr1, 3); // did this in order to get c in the buffer
    std::cout << "strArr1 is " << strArr1 << std::endl; // Is
    std::cin.ignore(3, 'p') >> strArr2; // ENTER Howard
    std::cout << "strArr2 is " << strArr2 << std::endl; // Howar
    return 0;
}

Notice that even though I gave it 5 characters (and terminating '\0') it "ate" 2 (+ \0) and the second var only held the first 5 chars (+ '\0). Why? Why didn't ignore also "count" the missing part of your name? That's because I told him to "use" only 3 characters, so he considered the current "eating" session as terminated once executed so it jumped to the next input session where "Howar" is porcessed. The 'd' is missing because strArray2 had no "space" left to save it in.
Hope this clarifies it on top of the comments.
N.B. you don't need to send only one value per std::cout, you can do multiple ones as shown in my example.
